# A way to determine Recurrence Equations? (General Approach)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

I am in the first stages of learning recursion for my a data structures class, and our professor has told us that we should be able to take a recursive method and be able to come up with problem size along with recurrence equations. I am able to write a recurrence equation when the problem size depends on one variable N that is assumed to be positive for simplicity such as:This method simply prints the input number as long as n > 0 at the first call.

```
public static int simpleCounter(int N) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        return 1 + simpleCounter(N - 1);
    }
 }
```

However when the problem size is more complicated, such as depending on 2 variables I am not able to create recurrence equations because I don't know what to do with variables. This method counts how many times 2 numbers can be subtracted from each other, assume count is always zero for the first call and a and b are both positive.

```
public static int complexCount(int a, int b, int count) {
    if ((a - b) <= 0) { 
        return 0; 
    }
    else {
      count = 1 + complexCount((a - b), b, count + 1)
      return count;
     }
 }
```

So what is the problem size here? Doesn't it have to do with both a and b?
And without knowing problem size I can't come up with recurrence equations:
Base: T(0) = 1 
Recurrence: T(N) = 1 + ??

Answer (score 0):

Recurrence relation don't always have to involve a single variable, and in fact it's common to have recurrence relations that are in multiple variables. Here, the recurrence relation would be

> T(a, b) = 1 + T(a - b, b) (if a ≥ b)
>
> T(a, b) = 1 (otherwise)

You could then solve this recurrence relation in terms of both a and b to derive your final solution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a similar question regarding this that I have no idea where to begin on... This helps in a way but can you elaborate on what you mean by "solve this recurrence relation in terms of both a and b"?